# Brown Spots on Fiesta Hibiscus

Tags: hibiscus

I’m new to the plant world and I have no idea why these brown spots are on my Fiesta Hibiscus. Please help. I also noticed some leaves turned completely yellow but I removed them. It’s an outdoor plant in Orlando. [image]Thank you in advance.